# Why does angularjs not work here

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was following a tutorial and i typed the code below
the angular folder in libs directory contains the minified verison of Angular js taken from https://angularjs.org/ the output i am getting is

{{author.name}}

{{author.title + ', ' + author.company }}

what is wrong here ?
can anyone please help thanx...!!!

```
<html lang="en" ng-app=>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
            <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.company }}</p>
        </div>
            <script>
            function MyController($scope)
            {
                $scope.author = {
                    'name':'aaa',
                    'title': 'bbb',
                    'company':'ccc'
                }
            }
            </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You seems to have something weird on your ng-app. Typo maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why angularjs isn't working in your case, is because of the VERSION of angular that you are using. I was able to get your app to work with Angular 1.2.1, but not Angular 1.4+. See example below:

Please follow @beri's answer for a working example with current Angular versions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
      <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.company }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function MyController($scope)
      {
        $scope.author = {
            'name':'aaa',
            'title': 'bbb',
            'company':'ccc'
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: thanx i got it now (Y)
is there a link where i can find up to date tutorials ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your app:

```
.... ng-app="myApp">
```

and init it:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    ...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your app name:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="my-app">
    <head>
        <title>Angular Demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
            <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.company }}</p>
        </div>
            <script>
            angular.module('my-app', []).controller('MyController' ,function MyController($scope)
            {
                $scope.author = {
                    'name':'aaa',
                    'title': 'bbb',
                    'company':'ccc'
                }
            });
            </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

With Angular you can define more than one application per one page, ut in most cases there is only one.
You can use it for modularization - creating independent parts of your page.

Code:

```
angular.module('my-app', []).controller(...,...)
```

Will register controller to `my-app` aplication. `[]` is used for required dependencies, that have to be included in order to my-app module to start.

Comment: this worked thanks but can you explain the code 

ngular.module('my-app', []).controller('MyController' ,function MyController($scope)
            {
                $scope.author = {
                    'name':'aaa',
                    'title': 'bbb',
                    'company':'ccc'
                }
            });
??

Comment: The tutorial @noob followed was using an older version of Angular than 1.4 which is why their code was not working. This is an example of how the app should be set up (up to date).

Comment: thanx i got it now (Y)
is there a link where i can find up to date tutorials ?